# DIVs flickering when positioning them fixed when scrolling inside a Div

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I have 4 DIVs and I am changing positions of 4 elements on scroll like below

```
 function adjustPositions(e) {
    var div = e ? $(this) : $('.parent');
    div.find('.left').css({
      left: div.scrollLeft() + "px"
    });
    var right = div.find('.right');
    right.css({
       left: div.scrollLeft() + div.width() - right.width() + "px"
    });
    div.find('.header').css({
       top: div.scrollTop() + "px"
    });
    var bottom = div.find('.footer');
    bottom.css({
      top: div.scrollTop() + div.height() - bottom.height() + "px"
    });
 }
 adjustPositions();
 $('.parent').on('scroll', adjustPositions);
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8NL2S/5/, when I am testing it in Safari, it flickers. Nothing fancy in this. Safari kicked my hopes like this in same case many times. How can I fix this.

Comment: what is the purpose of adjusting the position on scroll? can't you fix the divs just with relative css?

Comment: @jonasvermeulen Can you tell me how please..

Comment: position: fixed; in css will keep an element on a certain position even with scrolling, example here: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-fixed-position.php the yellow element on the right top of that page stays in that position

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you want. You're probably better off using a simple [css grid](http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/zDjRB/4/), or using a css grid framework like foundation, bootstrap or skeleton. Measuring certain css properties like width and height are actually quite expensive because the browser needs to perform calculations in order to return accurate information. This is ok if you're calling your adjustPositions function once or sparingly, but you're calling it each time the scroll event fires.

Comment: what do you actually looking for? maybe it can be done in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your div sizes are fixed and you want on same position in all browser then no need to call js function simply set css float:left; property with all your divs and use cf class on outer div of that 4 div. Example is:

```
HTML:

<div class="parent">
    <div class="static cf">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS:


.header{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    float:left;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10;
}
.left{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    left:0px;
    float:left;
    top:100px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.right{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    right:0px;
    float:left;
    top:100px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.footer{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:10;
}
.static{
    height:105px;
    width:410px;
    position:relative;
}
.cf{clear:both}
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be thinking too simple here, but doesn't position: fixed solve your problem?

I'm afraid there is no good solutions including javascript. Safari's speed in handling javascript just isn't good enough yet, to get a fluent animation.

Below you'll find the next best solution to solve your problem, using only css.

I edited your CSS to the following:

```
.header{
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10;
}
.left{
    height:1000px;
    width:100px;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.right{
    height:1000px;
    width:100px;
    right:0px;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.footer{
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:10;
}
.static{
    height:1000px;
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
}
```

I removed all javascript. Apart from that, nothing changed.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8NL2S/16/)

Answer (score 1):

You might looking for something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/sijav/8NL2S/12/ 
you must turn every `position:fixed` ... noo need to use JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Using `position:fixed` the way suggested above will position your inner divs relative to the window, and not the parent div. If you want to keep everything inside `.parent`, use the CSS below (no JS needed):

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
.header, .footer {
    position:fixed;
    width: 800px; /* .parent width */
    height:100px;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 300px; /* .parent hight - .footer hight */
}

.left, .right {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px; /* .parent height */
    background-color:#CCC;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 700px; /* .parent width - .right width */
}

.static {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

This should give the layout and behaviour you're trying to achieve without the flickering. You can try it below.

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/VYmHv/1/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your frames flicker because of the divs re-rendering/re-position when you scroll, due to their scroll functions. In order to prevent this you are best off using a different method of creating your display.

As you seem to use plain html with css and jquery files attached, there are many other ways of getting around your problem.

The first way would be to simply remove your scroll functions, it doesn't look like you need them. `position:fixed` would fix it so your divs follow you when you scroll.

the other way would be using any type of framework. This can be CSSGrid based as Kerry Liu showed an example of in the comments, or if you're desperate it can be html based (like `<frame>`).

If you have higher requirements for the styling then the positioning then perhaps there is a Jquery plugin available to help you further.